# How to determine shape of powers of curves?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm trying to understand how to figure out the shape of a given polynomial curve quickly.

$ax_1 + bx_2 = const$ gives a line.

$ax^2_1 + bx_2 = const$ gives a parabola.

$ax^2_1 + bx^2_2 = const$ gives an ellipse or hyperbola

$ax^3_1 + bx_2 = const$ gives st like $y=z^3$ (I don't know if it has a name)

This is the end of all I currently know.

$ax^3_1 + bx^2_2 = const$ gives what?

$ax^3_1 + bx^3_2 = const$ gives what?

$ax^4_1 + bx^2_2 = const$ gives what?

$ax^4_1 + bx^3_2 = const$ gives what?

$ax^4_1 + bx^4_2 = const$ gives what?

and so on...

I would be grateful if you could also give some general advice on how to deal with completely unfamiliar functions. (example: $sin^3(x) = ln (y)$ or $sin (x) = x^5$) Please, note that using software is not an option.

Comment: Try typing your graphs into http://www.graphsketch.com *or* http://www.wolphramalpha.com. It may not give you a *reason* as to why the graphs are shaped like that but you'll surely see a pattern as to how the graphs keep changing with increasing powers of variables. Just that you may have to use x and y instead of x_1 and x_2 while typing the graphs. Also, you may need to give values for constants because graphs vary with different constants.

Comment: Once you get past quadratic polynomials, shapes of curves get *much* harder to anticipate. See, for instance, [the wide variety of curves that arise from cubic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve). Isaac Newton undertook classifying these things, identifying 72 "species" ... and even he missed six of them. A quick web search for "cubic curves" turned-up [this short discussion of Newton's work](http://www.geogebra.org/static/Newton's%20Investigation%20of%20Cubic%20Curves%20-%20Jeffrey%20Nunemacher,%201993.pdf), which looks like an interesting overview.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.flipkart.com/play-graphs-magical-book-teaching-you-techniques-problem-solving-through-graph/p/itmdh6mtknpbjm3d (**Play with Graphs** by Amit Agarwal) is the perfect book that will meet your needs.

Comment: The link says “Something’s not right”